Why am I getting errors when calling wordnik api from python
I just signed up for a wordnik api key.  I took a small example to try using Python3.
I tried calling the api diretly from a browser and got valid replies using my API key.  I then coped an example from the wordnik site.  It generated the errors listed below.
I am wondering what I am doing wrong.  Perhaps someone has an example I could clone?
Thanks
Dan
from wordnik import *
apiUrl = 'http://api.wordnik.com/v4'
apiKey = 'MY API KEY REMOVED FOR THIS POSTING'
client = swagger.ApiClient(apiKey, apiUrl)

wordApi = WordApi.WordApi(client)
example = wordApi.getTopExample('irony')
print(example.text)

This generated the following error....
/Users/dkanze/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/.venv/bin/python /Users/dkanze/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2024.2/scratches/scratch_14.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/http/client.py", line 1336, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/http/client.py", line 1382, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/http/client.py", line 1331, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/http/client.py", line 1091, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/http/client.py", line 1035, in send
self.connect()
~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/http/client.py", line 1477, in connect
self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
server_hostname=server_hostname)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
sock=sock,
^^^^^^^^^^
...<5 lines>...
session=session
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
)
^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/ssl.py", line 1076, in _create
self.do_handshake()
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/ssl.py", line 1372, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1020)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dkanze/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2024.2/scratches/scratch_14.py", line 7, in 
example = wordApi.getTopExample('irony')
File "/Users/dkanze/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/wordnik/WordApi.py", line 225, in getTopExample
response = self.apiClient.callAPI(resourcePath, method, queryParams,
postData, headerParams)
File "/Users/dkanze/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/wordnik/swagger.py", line 73, in callAPI
request = urllib.request.urlopen(requestParams)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 189, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 495, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 604, in http_response
response = self.parent.error(
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 527, in error
result = self._call_chain(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 466, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 720, in http_error_302
return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 489, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 506, in _open
result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
'_open', req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 466, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 1367, in https_open
return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
context=self._context)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/urllib/request.py", line 1322, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1020)>
Process finished with exit code 1

Are you sure the api url is supposed to be http:, and not https: ?

I get the same error using https.  Thanks

I needed to do one thing.
I am running MacOS so I had to run the install certificate command in the python application folder.
Works!
